# C++ how to ignore string while reading from file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file

I have a program that opens a file, reads from the file and I need to ignore the strings from the file and save only the integers into variables.
So far I have tried with `file.ignore(' ')`, but it ignores only the first line.
Does anyone has an idea how I can fix this?

My code is:

```
ifstream file1;
int num1, num2, num3;
int intervalNumber1, intervalNumber2, intervalNumber3;
file1.open("file1.txt");
if (file1.fail()) {
    cout << "Error" << endl;
    exit(1);
} else {
    if (file1.is_open()) {
        file1 >> num1;
        file1 >> num2;
        file1 >> num3;

        file1 >> intervalNumber1;
        file1 >> intervalNumber2;
        file1 >> intervalNumber3;
    }
}
```

File1.txt

```
Number 40
Number1 34
Number2 100

Interval Number [20, 50]
Interval Number1 [60, 100]
Interval Number2 [110, 300]
```

Comment: Read the file in appropriate chunks (lines, whitespace-seperated strings, whatever), and ignore / strip the non-numeric parts manually.  Parse and assign the numeric parts as appropriate.

Comment: The file must have some sort of format description. Just extracting what looks like numbers is very likely going to fail eventually. Are there always 3 lines with `Number:` `Number1` `Number2` and then three with `Interval Number` `Interval Number1` `Interval Number2`?` Is this always what's in the file? 3 lines with data + one blank line + 3 more lines with data?

Comment: @StephanLechner there is an example of file1.txt

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yes there are always three lines with number, and three lines with interval number

Comment: you also "ignore" the `int` values you currently read from the file (you dont do anything with them), just do the same with `std::string`s

Comment: Is the order of `Number` `Number1` `Number2` `Interval Number` `Interval Number1` and `Interval Number2` fixed? If it is, why do the labels need to be in the file?

Comment: Without a proper specification, you may end up with a result like this: [all integers](https://godbolt.org/z/7TG3x4evq)

Comment: Do the answers below meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach is to read the strings the same way you read the integers. Assuming the format of the file is always the same and there is one word in the first the lines and two words in the next three lines and numbers are enclosed in `[]` and seperated by `,` you can just read the strings and the `[` and `]` and `,` in a `char`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss{R"(Number 40
Number1 34
Number2 100

Interval Number [20, 50]
Interval Number1 [60, 100]
Interval Number2 [110, 300])"};

    std::string dummy_string;
    char dummy_char;
    int number0=0;
    int number1=0;
    int number2=0;
    std::pair<int,int> interval0;
    std::pair<int,int> interval1;
    std::pair<int,int> interval2;

    ss >> dummy_string >> number0;
    ss >> dummy_string >> number1;
    ss >> dummy_string >> number2;
    ss >> dummy_string >> dummy_string >> dummy_char >> interval0.first >> dummy_char >> interval0.second >> dummy_char;
    ss >> dummy_string >> dummy_string >> dummy_char >> interval1.first >> dummy_char >> interval1.second >> dummy_char;
    ss >> dummy_string >> dummy_string >> dummy_char >> interval2.first >> dummy_char >> interval2.second >> dummy_char;

    std::cout << number0 << " " << number1 << " " << number2 << "\n";
    std::cout << interval0.first << " " << interval0.second << "\n";
    std::cout << interval1.first << " " << interval1.second << "\n";
    std::cout << interval2.first << " " << interval2.second << "\n";

}
```

Output:

```
40 34 100
20 50
60 100
110 300
```

Reading from a file stream instead of the string stream works the same.

---

You should consider to use a `std::vector` instead of naming variables `foo0`,`foo1`, `foo2` etc. Also consider to use a custom struct, for example if the numbers and the intervals belong together:

```
struct my_data {
    int number;
    int interval_start;
    int interval_stop;
};
```

For this type you can then overload the input operator `<<`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a [regular expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to solve this, if there is a known pattern.

If you just want to extract all numeric characters, using [std::copy_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to another array (eg a string) would do the job.

Another direct and performant option is, to read the file content into an array, (eg std::string) and iterate over the content, checking for numbers.

```
std::string file_content (... load file content);
for(char& c : file_content) {
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        have_fun_with_digit(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar actions using regular expressions

i am using two classes `std::regex` (std regular expression class), `std::smatch` (match results class) and algorithm `regex_search`. To read lines from a file, I use the `getNewLine` function, which skips empty lines

1. `std::regex` [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex)
   where I apply a pattern that is suitable for both cases  `NUMBER` and `[NUMBER, NUMBER]`. In all cases, the numbers are placed in separate groups. Pattern: `[ \\[](\\d+)[ ,]*(\\d+)?`
2. `std::smatch` [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results)
   which contains at position 0 the entire search string and further indices contain the found groups
3. `ReadNumber` function read line from file and get from line  `NUMBER` or `[NUMBER, NUMBER]` `match_results` which are converted to int by match group
4. `stoi` [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)  function converts found string of digits to int

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream file1;
regex re("[ \\[](\\d+)[ ,]*(\\d+)?");

bool getNewLine(ifstream& f, string& s) {
    while (getline(f, s)) 
        if (!s.empty()) return true;
    
    return false;
}

/*
*     t1 and t2 pointers for numbers read from the file, 
*     if t2 is nullptr then only one number is needed
*/
void ReadNumber(int *n1, int *n2=nullptr) {
    smatch m;
    string newLine;

    if (!getNewLine(file1, newLine))
        exit(1);

    //Checking if a string contains a match
    if (!regex_search(newLine, m, re))
        exit(1);

    *n1 = stoi(m[1]);
    cout << *n1;

    if (n2) {
        //Checking that the second group contains digits
        if(!m[2].length())
            exit(1);

        *n2 = stoi(m[2]);
        cout << " " << *n2;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int ArrSize = 3;
    int Numbers[ArrSize] = { 0,0,0 };
    pair<int, int> intervalNumber[ArrSize] = { {0,0},{0,0},{0,0} };

    file1.open("c:\\file1.txt");

    if (file1.fail()) {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ArrSize; i++)
        ReadNumber(&Numbers[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < ArrSize; i++)
        ReadNumber(&(intervalNumber[i].first), &(intervalNumber[i].second));

    file1.close();
    return 0;
}
```

results

```
40
34
100
20 50
60 100
110 300
```